# Windows 10 user rename

Tags: windows, windows-10, rename

Ive been reading into renaming user accounts on windows 10. but I had a question that I cannot seem to find an answer to or if this specific question has already been asked.

When renaming user trough settings it just simply renames the username but not the username folder. So what happends to al that is in that folder? and even to the pc. will the renamed user still be linked to that folder? or does it create a new one and loose all other data in the old username folder.

Also. if it creates a new folder. wouldnt I just be able to copy/paste almost all data from old folder to the new one?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change a User Account folder name in Explorer in Windows 10 by any currently known method. Any attempts to do so will result in various things getting corrupted.

While the User Account name can be changed in Settings, one cannot change the User folder name in Windows 10 without reinstalling.  Any attempt using Regedit or other bypasses to change Profile Image Path in registry will most likely cause a failure (loop at the Lock Screen).

If you want a new user name, just create a new profile.